# Using B3 JIT as a backend for a statically compiled language

Tags: compiler-construction

Recently I have learned about [B3 (Bare Bones Backend)](https://webkit.org/docs/b3/), this is a very fast compiler backend created for WebKit JavaScript engine. Fast like it compiles quickly, 5 times faster than LLVM (which they have used before). I am working on a AOT compiled language right now which at the moment compiles to C, but I thought I would like to use B3 because of compilation speed, and because I loved it's simplicity, it's semantics are similar to the language I am creating, it can probably do stack traces much easier than doing it in C (using `#line` directives, DWARF symbolic info, `addr2line`), it is going to be cross-platform (at least x64 and ARM are claimed). But I only started to learn about B3, can anyone discuss if this backend is at all possible to use for a compiled language? I realize it was made with JIT in mind, but it generates machine code, right? What work must be done to be able to save generated code into object file and then linking? If it is possible, how to start about it?